# Why is Mining Fatigue depicted as a spoon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, the mining fatigue status effect reduces mining speed. But what the heck does the icon mean? Is that a spoon? If so, how does a spoon represent mining slower?

[image]

Comment: Although the answer is quite easy given (because it is funny and spoons make for bad tools for mining) this question is definetly off-topic, because it is asking about game design. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Because spoons are terrible mining tools.